# How to connect two projects routes in NodeJS and react( I wan to call react in NodeJS project)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to connect two projects one is reactJS and another is NodeJS. It should be called NodeJS is to be run on localhost:3000 and it running fine. then I call another react application that is redirecting on port localhost:3001. My question is that how can I connect localhost:3000 NodeJS project to react so that react first call NodeJS project and then by clicking link it goes to react app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C27DI.png)

Comment: For quick fix, I recommend adding a redirect to your react application from your nodejs application,so that when ever user go to localhost:3000, they will be redirected to localhost:3001

Answer (score 0):

You can build your react app each time you build your node app.

In your package.json in your node app, modify your start script to:

"start":"rm -rf ./build && cd ./src && npm run build && cd .. && node server.js" //or nodemon

Now serve your files from your node app. For instance, with express;

```
const assetsRoot = path.join(__dirname,'./build') //require path
app.use(express.static(assetsRoot))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(${assetsRoot}/index.html`))
})
```

And point your browser to your node app (No need to run the react dev server).This would be slower than the usual build process for obvious reasons.

You could also use a proxy or use a proxy middleware but that wouldnt redirect to your node instance for the original request or when the content-type is text/html.

If you'd like to serve the root html page from your react dev server and send all other api requests to your node instance, then the proxy approach would work. Simple add;

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:3000",
```

in your package.json in your react app.

Comment: this is showing errors in server.js on coping code in Registration-and-Login-Form-in-Nodejs-and-MongoDB-master/server.js

Comment: and i have copy & paste "start":"rm -rf ./build && cd ./src && npm run build && node server.js" code in Registration-and-Login-Form-in-Nodejs-and-MongoDB-master/package.json

Comment: Please try again. It was missing “cd ..”. 

Also, how and where are you placing this line? Try to provide a screenshot if it doesn’t work.